# Asp.Net:Binding Model property value in Razor cshtml from QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to binding Model class property value from url query parameters but it's seems not working.

**Browser Redirected url from App1 to app2:**

> http://localhost:9040/app2/Home/UserNameAuthentication?tenantName=testtenant

**Application1:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ApplicationSwitcher()
{
  var redirectUrl="http://localhost:9040/app2/Home/UserNameAuthentication?tenantName=testtenant";   
  return Redirect(redirectUrl);     
}
```

**Application2:**

**ModelClass:**

```
public class LoginModel
{
  public string tenantName {get;set;}
}
```

**UserNameAuthentication ViewPage cshtml**

```
<div class="inner-box">

        @using ICommonInterfaces.Model

        @model LoginModel
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UsernameAuthentication", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
          @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenantName"]))
          {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.tenantName, ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenantName"].ToString())
          }
          else
          {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.tenantName)
          }
          <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="rectangle" id="submitNext" disabled="disabled" />
}
</div>
```

**HomeController:**

```
public IActionResult UsernameAuthentication()
{
  //retrived redirection request and open current viewpage.
  return View();
}

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UsernameAuthentication(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(loginModel.tenantName);//null
    }
```

what is the reason i am getting null? And how to get value and set to loginModel propery(tenantName) by extract from query or querystring url?

Thanks.

Comment: it's not working with [FromQuery] also...`public async Task<IActionResult> UsernameAuthentication([FromQuery] LoginModel loginModel)`....bcz i saw in HttpContext.Request.Path got changed

Comment: @r08 How did you test the `[FromQuery]` ? if you're using a form you should use `[FromForm]`.

Comment: When I replicated your code, It seems working for me. same code same Implementation

Comment: i am trying from another application and redirecting to above mention url app...and it's redirected and opened cshtml page which i provided in above sample...now on sumbit i want values with binded properties in the HomeControler method `public async Task<IActionResult> UsernameAuthentication(LoginModel loginModel){}`...but it's not working.

Comment: @HMZ i provided before method argument both `FromQuery` and `FromForm`..but both not working...please provide details context

Comment: Could you able to update the question with POST handler action and HTML? maybe you are missing  AntiForgeryToken when posting it

Comment: updated with more detailed.

Comment: I can see the code update.To understand myself.  ```UsernameAuthentication``` is not displaying the view, because ```LoginModel loginModel``` getting null on ```async Task<IActionResult> UsernameAuthentication`` here right?

Comment: @Raju yes,getting loginModel null in `[HttpGet....Task<IActionResult>UsernameAuthentication.....

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo(app1=>controller action=>cshtml=>controller action):

app2:HomeController(localhost:44358):

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult UsernameAuthentication(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            //retrived redirection request and open current viewpage.
            return View(loginModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UsernameAuthenticationPost(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            return Ok(loginModel);
        }
```

app2:Startup.cs:

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                                  });
            });
           
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
           
           
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

app1:Controller(localhost:44389),I use https in my project,redirect to app1:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ApplicationSwitcher()
        {
            var redirectUrl = "https://localhost:44358/Home/UserNameAuthentication?tenantName=testtenant";
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

UserNameAuthentication.cshtml(I change it to post,and change the ActionName):
@model LoginModel

```
<div class="inner-box">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UsernameAuthenticationPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenantName"]))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.tenantName, ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["tenantName"].ToString())
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.tenantName)
        }
        <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="rectangle" id="submitNext"/>
    }
</div>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Good Job, I thought to replicate but been busy. Upvoting for the effort.

Comment: thanks for the your valueable time and effort...+v1...but still i didn't get in your example how and from where ```[HttpGet......UsernameAuthentication(LoginModel loginModel....``` value binding...and i seen in redirecturl `/app/Home/...` app name missing it's not the case because same app it's binding...it will be easy for me to update my existing app code..

Comment: In the sample,there're two apps,public async Task<IActionResult> ApplicationSwitcher()=>redirect to  [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult UsernameAuthentication(LoginModel loginModel),in the project includes HomeController,I add cors to it.I have updated my answer to share more about cors.